# Unable to change location for firebase pubsub trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-cli

I have an App Engine app in asia-northeast1, but i could not specify the region for pubsub trigger.

This works:

```
functions.region("asia-northeast1").https.onRequest(async (req, res)
```

This does not work:

```
functions.region("asia-northeast1").pubsub.schedule('* 6-23 * * *')
```

With the following erroor message: Error: HTTP Error: 400, Location must equal asia-northeast1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in asia-northeast1

Does anyone have any experience getting pubsub trigger to work in a different region than the default us-central1? Thank you in advance

Comment: it is fixed now in v7.1.1 https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1500) in the Firebase CLI version 7.1.0.  Downgrade to a prior version for now (7.0.2).  This will be fixed.

When you encounter unexpected problems with the Firebase CLI, you should [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support), and also consider filing a bug report in GitHub.

Comment: This issue isn't just related to the version of firebase CLI and so this answer becomes quite dated. My CLI output tells me I'm using the right region then tells me I'm not, and that's with 7.4.0...!

Comment: @MattFletcher Please file a bug on github using the same repo as linked in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here: I've resolved setting `Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location` in Firebase *Project settings*, which was *undefined*, to `eur3 (europe-west)` (my *AppEngine* resources are in `europe-west1`)